# Reschedule Task after Completion in Java

Tags: java, job-scheduling

I want to develop an app with Java that will fetch some files in the Internet every 24h after it has finished. It will start every time on startup and will be on Window's task bar.

### Steps:

1. Start the GUI (windows startup);
2. Automatic trigger to perform task;
3. Do the job;
4. Print task results on the GUI;
5. After the task is completed, schedule the task for 24h from now;

And the steps 3-5 would be repeated every time the app has performed its task.

I'm facing a lot of problems with the usage of Timer and TimerTask.

I was thinking about an architecture similar to this:

Main Runner Class (Just initialization of GUI and jobs);
GUI handler Class;
Job Performer Class;

**How can should I proceed to schedule the Job Performer Class to perform again after it has completed its goal?**

Comment: What exactly problems are you facing? `Timer` supports scheduling repeated tasks. Although clearly you are using a far-from-ideal tool to solve your problem, you didn't say how exactly you are failing.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to be notified when the TimerTask class has completed its task.

Comment: There is no need to be notified of that. Call `scheduleAtFixedRate` and the task will run repeatedly without the need to reschedule.

Comment: But I want to schedule just one instance. The next one will be scheduled 24h after this one was completed. It is not something like: "Trigger everyday at 2pm"

Comment: So you want to schedule with a delay of 24h from the end of one job till the start of the next one? That's what the `schedule` method achieves. I don't see the difference between scheduling once with a set delay and rescheduling once the job is done. The behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's not completely true. If task n takes a longer time than the interval (which absolutely is possible) the timer will busy-run pending tasks and _not_ reschedule them <interval> milliseconds after task n completed.

Comment: @YngveSneenLindal You are right, (n+1)st execution is scheduled relative to the *start* of nth execution, not its *end*.

Comment: I arrived here because of my recently asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754014/how-can-i-schedule-java-tasks-at-guaranteed-fixed-rate-independent-of-task-run